# app.windows() returning empty list when application is started in virtual environment

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

Tried to automate postman application using pywinauto in python virtual environment

```
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop
filePath = <FilePath>
app = Application(backend='uia').start(filePath, timeout=10)
print(app.windows())
```

Everytime I execute this code I am getting empty list output and the application is opening as GUI

Can someone explain why the strange issue happening and this is not happening in normal environment(not a virtual env)

Answer (score 0):

support you can use subprocess module to start the process first, then use desktop automation library to recognized the control and do operation.

Comment: This is strange issue happening with application, this is fixed by connecting the application to the app instance, like `app.connect(path=<filePath>)`

Comment: you can try this library, it will do application/window attach automatically,  the application,window, control are stored in locator. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ClickCorp.clicknium